# Django Slug field only generated when new models made, not old migrated models

Tags: python, django, slug

I have a django model object that has a slug field, but this slug only gets set once, when the model is created. The problem is that I have migrated over a large database of these models from a previous version of the app that did not have a slug field so the slug field is now null on all the old objects. How can I rewrite my model or any part of my views to automatically populate the slug field of all of my old model objects, not just the new ones being created?

```
class NewLink(models.Model):
     newlinktag = models.ForeignKey('pageinfo', related_name='newlink_newlinktag') #tags link to which username it belongs to
     linkcomment = models.CharField(max_length=512) #comment to go along with post
     url = models.URLField(max_length = 1024) #actual submitted link, need max length so we don't get hacked
     slug = models.SlugField(('slug'), max_length=512, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
         self.slug = slugify(self.linkcomment)
         super(newlink, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

     def __unicode__(self):
         return self.url
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to write you convertor(updater) into the migration file (in forward case). And if you want you can implement backward case

Example here http://concentricsky.com/blog/2014/jan/data-migrations-south-and-django

Comment: To avoid making another migration, is there some loop I can write or create a @property so when it is accessed instead of the slug field it auto generates the slug? Just trying to get it working this time specifically without migrating again

Comment: I think it's not good idea. The best practice keep all slugs in database.

Comment: Actually I just fixed it simply by doing this in manage.py shell in my EC2 server:
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
c = NewLink.objects.all()
for link in c:
    link.slug = slugify(link.linkcomment)
    link.save()
And it works perfectly now. The loop took VERY LONG to finish haha.